# 3 sum conjecture if P=NP

Tags: parameterized-complexity

If P=NP then we have W[1]=FPT. Would it just imply $k$-sum conjecture fails for some large $k$ or $k$ can be as small as $3$?

Comment: Even if the running time is $k^{\lceil k/2 \rceil} \cdot n$, it is not necessarily bounded by $O(n^{\lceil k/2 \rceil - \epsilon})$.

Comment: O(n) is in O(n^{k/2})

Comment: This would depend on whether $k$-Sum is in $W[t]$, is this known?

Comment: @Discretelizard https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258441995_On_the_parameterized_complexity_of_k-SUM If derandomization assumption is true then yes. Although the k-sum conjecture is formulated in regards to randomized algorithms.